# Archiva/Maven failed to execute goal

Tags: maven, archiva

When I try to build using **Archiva/Maven**, the system return this message:

*Failed to execute goal on project ... The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.sf.josql:josql:jar:1.5, net.sf.josql:gentlyweb-utils:jar:1.5: Failure to find net.sf.josql:josql:jar:1.5 in ... repository/internal was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ... has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove from your local repository directory (or all file with version 1.5):

$M2_HOME/repository/net/fs/josql/josql

Answer (score 0):

It only work when I change from Archiva to Maven (local). Need further investigation...